# Ownerdraw button's hover effect

Tags: c++, winapi

I set the ownerdraw button.
I make it with Rectangle and using message WM_DRAWITEM.
And in the button, succeeded to judge ON/OFF.
But I want to add the hover effect as css's :hover.
I want to change the color darker taking a few seconds.
It is difficult.
I searched for some days.But I cannot find solution.
This is my first question.
I am sorry for poor English.

I tried to catch the mouse (x,y).
But I cannot.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
x = LOWORD(lp); 
y = HIWORD(lp); 


if(buttonlefttop<= x <= buttonlefttop + buttonwidth && buttontoptop<= y 
<= buttontoptop + buttonheight){
            std::cout<<"[INFO] "<<"ON\n";
}else{
            std::cout<<"[INFO] "<<"OFF\n";
}
```

case WM_DRAWITEM:
            hdc = ((LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)(lp))->hDC;

```
        if (((LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)(lp))->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) {
            hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(80, 91, 109));
            hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(80, 91, 109));

            SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
            SelectObject(hdc, hbr);

            std::cout<<"[INFO] ON\n";
        }else {
            hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(73, 147, 120));
            hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(73, 147, 120));

            SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
            SelectObject(hdc, hbr);

            std::cout<<"[INFO] OFF\n";
        }
        Rectangle(hdc , 0 , 0 ,
         buttonwidth,buttonheight
        );
        DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc , GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)));
        return TRUE;
```

I cannot add hovereffect.

Comment: I guess you need to start a timer to `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler that will periodically update color and invalidate button window triggering repaint. Also I should mention that `hpen` handle leaks and that you should keep the handles returned by first invocation of `SelectObject` to put select them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Buffered Animation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-beginbufferedanimation), which is available since Windows Vista. This is the same API that standard Win32 controls use internally to draw animated fade effects.

The API takes care of:

- creating a bitmap for the first image of the fade animation
- creating a bitmap for the last image of the fade animation
- creating a timer to periodically call `WM_PAINT`
- generating the intermediate images of the animation

You basically only have to render the first and last images of the animation and the API automatically renders the steps in between.

There are many samples on the Web for using this API. There is already one on the API page I linked above. There is a [tutorial on CodeGuru](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/vista/article.php/c15841/Using-the-Windows-VistaWindows-7-BuiltIn-Buffered-Animation-API.htm) which has better explanations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function is first time to see.I will try it now. Thank you.